# How to link notes in macOS Notes application?

Tags: macos, notes.app

Is it possible to link to another notes in macOS Notes Application? For example I want to add in link to "Note2" from "Note1". So I click on the link, it will take me to that note.

Comment: The following reddit page has a list of iOS url schemes, https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/3mux7h/ios_url_schemes/. Using that in combination with the iOS developer docs, it may be possible. Getting the note Id to pass into the URL query may not be possible. I will test as soon as I can and write back. `mobilenotes://` is the URL of interest.

Answer (score 5):

If you click on the “Add People” button in the top right corner, it will take you to a version of the iOS Share Sheet. Choose “Copy Link” and then select “Copy Link” again in the top right corner.

It will upload the note to your iCloud and give you a URL. Still trying to figure out how to get the “ID” from the link to use `mobilenotes://` (since that would be easier).